# MVC 4 Authentication Using Forms and Azure ACS

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have made a MVC 4 Project, set up to authenticate using STS (Azure ACS). Everyhing works. People can sign in using Google,Facebook or Live ID.

My Question is now from a design point of view. Could i expect people to always have one of aboves to sign in with?  Can i add Twitter to Azure ACS also?

Would it be a good idea to also add forms login and give people the option to register an user as in the old days and sign in?  How do i do this ? Is it just to enable forms authentication again in web.config.

```
<!--Commented out by Identity and Access VS Package-->
<!--<authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" /></authentication>-->
```

Right now when i put Aothorize on a controller, it redirect me to :

```
http://localhost:48451/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fAbout
```

How do i solve that? Im thinking that enabling the forms authentication again might solve it - but i would like some comments on the design first before just doing it.